# Recursive reversing a sentence code. Why constant pointer to a constant char?

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, constants, reverse

When I run below code with

```
 void reverse(char *ptr)
```

it works. But in textbook function prototype is such:

```
 void reverse(const char * const ptr )
```

Why is it like that? In the first one I assume my pointer can point to a different address and the value it points to can be changed. In the textbook protoype,  both the address and the value it points to can not be changed. But do we want this? At first sight because it is recursive, the value it points to and address need to be changed in order to function. Maybe I am missing something here.

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    void reverse(char *ptr);

    int main(void)
    {
        char sentence[80];
        puts("Enter a sentence");
        fgets(sentence,80,stdin);
        reverse(sentence);
        getch();
    }

    //recursive reverse function
    void reverse(char *ptr)
    {

        if (ptr[0]=='\0')
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            reverse(&ptr[1]);
            putchar(*ptr);
        }
    }
```

Comment: What textbook? Any textbook that provides that signature is wrong.

Comment: Deitel C How to Program 6th Edition

Comment: Well, I missed that all this function does is print the string in reverse ... a side effect. But I missed this because your question makes no sense in that light. Why would you think that the signature is wrong, when the function doesn't change anything? "the value it points to and address need to be changed in order to function" -- No, it's evident that nothing changes ... each recursive invocation has its own parameters and local variables.

Comment: If nothing changes it is not necessary to add const modifiers? Why add extra when not needed?

Comment: const is never necessary ... but it prevents misuse and sometimes aids the compiler in generating better code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the function `reverse` is misleading as it suggest that the array is reversed in place. The name should be `print_reversed` or something since it doesn't change the array but print it reversed on the screen. Then there is nothing strange having it `const char * const ptr`.

Comment: But how will it be possible? We declare that ptr can not be adjusted to show different address and then we are modifying it to a different address by feeding the pointer with the next characters address? const means it can not be modified to get a different address or am I wrong?

Comment: @user1939432 Nothing is being modified ... the `ptr` of each invocation of the function is distinct.

Comment: Is this because each recursive call gets a different copy of ptr ? If function was not recursive this would not work right?

Comment: @user1939432 All calls of all functions get unique local variables and parameters; the compiler doesn't know what functions are recursive and would have to go out of its way to make recursion not work. You can break it by using static variables (but there are no static parameters).

Comment: @user1939432: A const variable cannot be modified, but copies thereof can: `const int i=40; int j = i+2;` and `const int i=40; printf("%d\n", i+2);` are both legal.